# serching in a sub directory of a site/forum

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I'm looking to find a way to search in a specific directory of a forum, there are tools to search in a specific site but is there any tool to search in a specific sub directory?

for example search for a word in "forum.example.com/xxx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Google to do this: search term

```
site:forum.example.com inurl:/sub-directory/
```

You can use any browser for this.